# Sort String array both lexicographically and then Numerically(as string contains digits)

Tags: java, string

I have a string that contains numbers in it . I want to sort it like the output should be lexicographically sorted and then according to numbers in the end. I have done this in below way bit the complexity of this is very big. Is there any other way to sort this?
**Don't want to use Arrays.sort directly**

Output Expected- [blue1, blue3, red3, red6]

```
 public class SortStrings {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a[] = { "blue3", "red6", "red3","blue1" };
    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a.length - i-1; j++) {
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                tmp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(a);
      Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
            }

            int extractInt(String s) {
                String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                // return 0 if no digits found
                return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
            }
        });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

}

Comment: What does "both lexicographically and numerically" mean?  What result would you like to see from your example data?

Comment: hi @KevinAnderson - I have updated my question, I hope its more clear now. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: What if the data were, say, {red25, blue3, red6, blue19}: should that sort as {blue3, blue19, red6, red25}, rather than {blue19, blue3, red25, red6}?

Comment: You are sorting the entire list lexicographically first, and then you are sorting the entire list by the numbers at the end - so obliterating the results of the first sort!   What I think you are after is a single comparator that compare first by the leading non-numeric, then only if that is equal by the numbers at the end.

Comment: What if you add "blue201" to the list? Where would it end up?

Comment: @racraman How to do that in single comparator?

Comment: The `compare` method takes the two strings to be compared, so within that method you perform ALL the comparisons (compare text part first, then if that’s equal compare the numbers).  Invoke that by `Collections.sort` just as you do above.